# ASP.NET Boilerplate SqlException at first run

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

After download/restore zip template for ABP v2.3.0 i had the following exception raised after the first application run

`stack track here`https://pastebin.com/g2XYAwp1

Before first execution  I did the following steps:

1. Opened solution on Visual Studio 2015
2. Changed the database connection string
3. Restored nuget packages for the solution
4. Select the 'Web' project as startup project
5. Run the EntityFramework's 'Update-Database' command

(database created successfully)

Run the application

Unfortunately I don't have the ability to work with VS2017 (and then to use ABP 3.0 template generated online)

It's possibile to download ABP v2.3.0 template as generated [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) ?

Comment: accept @aaron answer if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After download/restore zip template for ABP v2.3.0 i had the following exception raised after the first application run

The exception is from a missing foreign key reference in `AbpSettings`.

Remove invalid entries in that table and your application should run fine.

> It's possibile to download ABP v2.3.0 template as generated [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) ?

You can only choose the project version for premium startup templates.

You can build your own from [module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v2.5.1](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v2.5.1).

Comment: Thanks @aaron for the quick response!

Releated to the "AbpSettings" issue 

After downloaded https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/releases/tag/v2.1.1

Comment: Thanks @aaron for the quick response!

Releated to the "AbpSettings" issue i have manually deleted FOREIGN KEY "FK_dbo.AbpSettings_dbo.AbpUsers_UserId" from database and now works fine , so i don't understand why standard template made this issue


Releated to ABP v.2.3.0 issue, after downloaded zip from https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/releases/tag/v2.1.1 (i'm using module-zero-template template MPA)  what steps should I take to properly configure the "AbpCompanyName" prefix?

Renaming Files / Folders?

Comment: What do you mean by "made this issue Releated to ABP v.2.3.0 issue"? Yes, you need to rename the files and folders yourself.